# Number of experiments

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How many independent trials should be performed so that the following inequality is true, with the probability higher or equal to 0.975. The inequality is:

$$|X_n/n - p| < 0.1, $$
where $X_n$ is the number of positive realizations of in $n$ trials, and $p=0.5$ is the probability of a positive realization of one trial. Find the average for the minimum number of trials using the De Moivre-Laplace theorem.

I just don't understand what I am supposed to do here, so I haven't really tried anything.

Comment: For large n, you can treat $X_n$ as to be from normal distribution $N \sim (np, \sqrt(np(1-p)))$. Now if we look at your inequality, which can be written as $|X_n -np| \le 0.n$. So basically you need to find n for which normal distribution has 0.975 probability in region $np\pm0.n$.

Comment: A good first step is to look up (or remember) the DeMoivre-Laplace Theorem. The theorem relates the binomial distribution (which you apparently started with) to the normal distribution. And that's a hint to continue as in the previous comment.